# Jenkins Slave can't read settings.xml

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, docker, settings

I have created a jenkins slave image for Docker, which I want to use to build all of my Java projects, however, I can't work out how to reference the .m2/settings.xml file to tell it where to pull from.

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM openjdk:8
MAINTAINER Chris Hudson <chudson@amelco.co.uk>

RUN apt-get -qqy update && \
    apt-get -y install openssh-server sudo

RUN useradd -m -u 1000 -s /bin/bash jenkins && \
    mkdir -p /home/jenkins/.ssh && \
    mkdir -p /home/jenkins/.m2 && \
    echo jenkins:jenkins | chpasswd && \
    mkdir -p /etc/sudoers.d/ && \
    echo "jenkins ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/jenkins && \
    chmod 440 /etc/sudoers.d/jenkins

COPY id_rsa.pub /home/jenkins/.ssh/authorized_keys
COPY settings.xml /home/jenkins/.m2/

RUN chown -R jenkins:jenkins /home/jenkins

RUN mkdir -p /var/run/sshd

EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

But when I run the build, it attempts to pull from maven central, and not our local Artifactory instance, which is configured in the settings file.

This works when I run it on Jenkins Master, but I want to offload the builds to the slaves, but I can't work out how to configure Maven correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your workspace is mounted from the slave. and it's not read the .m2 from your container

you can try use his plugin - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin  to create the settings.xml and configure your MVN build step to use it.

Comment: The slave itself is a container. I think the jenkins master connects directly with this slave container and does not interact with the docker host system at all (port 22 is forwarded to the slave container's sshd). This means the workspace is also inside the slave container. I like the plugin you mentioned though :)

Comment: I think you should try the plugin , you will have your configuration in one generic place , it's easy to use. If you need any help let me know